# how do i populate the UITableView with the column data from the external database(mysql)?

Tags: iphone

hi i am trying to connect to the external database and then populate the UITableView with the column data in the external database(mysql)... could anyone help me out...

Comment: do you know how to populate a UITableView with the contents of an array?

do you know how to get data out of a mysql database?

put the two together

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a php page to grab the data out of MySQL, then use json_encode() to prepare the data for the app.

Next you'll need something like [this](http://www.mobileorchard.com/tutorial-json-over-http-on-the-iphone/) to translate the JSON into a list on the iPhone.

Comment: Assuming that Akshayk is using PHP